# Is there a Mac OS X equivalent of the Linux iwconfig command?

Tags: wifi, command-line, unix

I'm looking for a command line tool in Mac OS X that performs the equivalent of the [iwconfig](http://manpg.es/iwconfig.8) command in Linux.

Example:

```
kirkland@x220:~/src/byobu/byobu$ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"serenity"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:11:22:33:44:55   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-17 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:70   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`ifconfig` gives information about all interfaces, including WLAN. The WLAN interface is usually `en1`.

```
$ ifconfig en1
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 20:c9:d0:97:22:e9 
        inet6 fe80::22c9:d0ff:fe97:22e9%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
        inet 192.168.1.137 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        media: autoselect
        status: active
```

`airport -I` gives information about WLAN interfaces (check out the man page for additional options)

```
$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I en1
     agrCtlRSSI: -68
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -85
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station 
     lastTxRate: 54
        maxRate: 54
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: 11:22:33:44:55:66
           SSID: serenity
            MCS: -1        channel: 6
```

Comment: iwconfig can turn off/on the adapter, can airport do that too? Also, is airport part of the default command set? I can see `man airport`, but `airport` on its own doesn't seem to exist on my system (Mac OSX 10.13.6).

Comment: @crs1138 Did you check `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport`?

Comment: Both `ifconfig en1` and `airport -I` (with the full path given in @nohillside's comment) work on OSX