# List of all interfaces in my laptop

Tags: macos, network, command-line

Below is the machine:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin whatever 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sun Dec  1 18:59:03 PST 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.19~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$
```

---

In ubuntu, `ip addr` or `ip a` gives list of all interfaces.

What is the similar command in mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find my IP Address from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20547/how-do-i-find-my-ip-address-from-the-command-line)

Comment: In **Terminal**, try: `ifconfig`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39351/313842 ... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/80191/313842

Comment: All Interfaxes including USB etc or just network Interfaces (ethernet, wifi etc)?

Comment: @nohillside On ubuntu, would `ip` give USB too?

Comment: @ankii I don‘t know, that‘s why it‘s up to the OP to explain „all Interfaces“ :-)

Comment: @nohillside after setting up Ubuntu in Parallels and running the `man ip` in Terminal, It struck me: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/ip.8.html

Answer (score 3):

`networksetup -listallnetworkservices` is the macOS command that I believe you are looking for.

Quoting from `man networksetup`:

> -listallnetworkservices
>
> Displays a list of all the network services on the server's hardware ports. An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.

On my MacBook Air:

```
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
Wi-Fi
iPhone USB
Bluetooth PAN
Thunderbolt Bridge
```

There's also `ifconfig` which will show you IP addresses and MAC addresses, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: The correct answer to the question is `ifconfig -a` as it will list *all* interfaces; both physical and logical (virtual).  Less correct is `networksetup -listallhardwareports` which will list all of the physical interfaces and the least correct is `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` which only lists the services available.  Also `ifconfig` does much, much more than show IP and MAC addresses.